# Find the number of arrangements of $k \mbox{  }1'$s, $k \mbox{  }2'$s, $\cdots, k \mbox{  }n'$s - total $kn$ cards.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of arrangements of $k \mbox{  }1'$s, $k \mbox{  }2'$s, $\cdots, k \mbox{  }n'$s - total $kn$ cards - so that
no same numbers appear consecutively. For $k=2$ we can compute it by using the 
PIE, and it is $$\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (2n-i)! 2^i$$

Comment: We have seen similar problems here before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76213/how-many-arrangements-of-a-2b-3c-4d-5e-have-no-identical-consecutive-lett  My impression is that there is no general formula for the solution, but I would love to be proven wrong!

Comment: quite different problem!

Comment: Not so different.

Comment: the problem you mentioned deals with the different number of cards, but here we consider the same number of cards.

Comment: The cases $k=2$ and $k=3$ are tabulated here: https://oeis.org/A114938 and https://oeis.org/A193638 . For $k=3$ there is no simple formula given.

Comment: @Byron Thanks for the compliments.  I'm not sure I understand your bounty - what would merit the award?

Comment: Hmm, I have not previously worked with Laguerre polynomials, but it seems that they have a simple expansion in terms of my $q_k$ polynomials: $L_k(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i q_i(x)$!  That's rather nice.

Comment: @Jair Sorry, I should have explained. I will simply award you the bounty, but I have to wait 24 hours. I will give it to you sometime tonight.

Comment: Ah, yes - I figured that out after posting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe the answer is given by $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} q_k(x)^n \, dx$$ where $q_k(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{i-k}}{i!} {k-1 \choose i-1}x^i$ for $k\geq 1$, and $q_0(x) = 1$.  In general if we allow $k_i$ of the $i$<sup>th</sup> number the answer should be  $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \prod_i q_{k_i}(x) \, dx$$

You can check that this agrees with the sequences [oeis.org/A114938](http://oeis.org/A114938) and [oeis.org/A193638](http://oeis.org/A193638) above.  I do not (quite) have a proof of this, although I'm very close. The method is my own, and has not been published anywhere as far as I know. I'd be happy to give you more information in private, but I'm not sure I want to expose it publicly until it's proven.  Please let me know if you think this is noteworthy and any potential applications.

Edit:  Following some information given to me by Byron, I found that this formula is already known and that in fact $q_n(x) = (-1)^{n}L_n^{(-1)}(x)$ where $L_n^{(\alpha)} (x) $ denotes the generalized Laguerre polynomial.  See Section 6 [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/rookp.pdf) for a labelled version. I should have mentioned this sooner; thanks Byron!

Comment: I must be missing something. When $k=2$ and $n=1$, the correct answer is zero, but that's not what your formula gives.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry!  I forgot a factor of $(-1)^{i-k}$ in the expression for $q_k$.  I will fix it.

Comment: You can check that $q_2(x) = -x + \frac{x^2}{2}$ and then $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} ( -x + \frac{x^2}{2}) \, dx = 0$ as desired.

Comment: Here is some numerical evidence in the form of a Sage worksheet - it reproduces oeis.org/A114938.  See http://sagenb.org/home/pub/4677/

Comment: Well, I'm convinced! That is a wonderful formula.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I just need to figure out something I can do with it. :)

Comment: @jair Thanks for the answer. By the way, is there any recursion formula for $q_k (x)$'s?

Comment: Yes - I don't know if this helps, but $q_k(x) = \int_0^x q_{k-1}(t)\, dt - q_{k-1}(x)$.  Also, $q_k(x)$ is the inverse Laplace of  $(1-x)^{k-1}/x^{k+1}$.  Can I ask why this question came up?

Comment: One of my students asked me several days ago. No other reasons! Your previous comments are greatly helpful.