# No two identical ranks together in a standard deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that a shuffled standard deck of 52 cards has no two cards of the same rank together ?

I am unable to get a handle on this problem, and wonder whether there is an analytical solution ?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, please consider voting up Jair Taylor's answer. It's a favorite of mine, and I think it deserves recognition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jair Taylor's [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129451/find-the-number-of-arrangements-of-k-mbox-1s-k-mbox-2s-cdots/129802#129802). Put $k=4$ and $n=13$ to find the number of arrangements where no two cards of the same rank are together. The number of such arrangements turns out to be $$4184920420968817245135211427730337964623328025600.$$
Dividing by $52!/(4!)^{13}$ gives the probability: $.045476$.

---

**Added:** If you are willing to use an approximation, the number $Z$ of cards of the same rank that are together is approximately a Poisson random variable with mean $3$. Therefore,
$$P(Z=0)\approx e^{-3}= .049787.$$

Comment: Thanks, and wow for Taylor's answer !