# What is the probability of shuffling a deck of cards, & coming up with an order of cards that doesn't have any 2 cards of the same value back to back?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, card-games

This is a question that I have been struggling with for quite some time.  I work with kids at a math tutoring center, and one of the things we do is work on the multiplication facts.  We use a standard 52 card deck, numbered 0-12, with 4 of each value.  We begin by flipping one card face up.  This is the number the student will work on.  The instructor then flips one card at a time until all 52 cards are used.  After doing this for a few days I started to notice that cards of the same value would come up back to back quite often.  So I began to wonder...

What is the probability of flipping through the entire deck without ever having 2 cards of the same value coming up back to back?

I believe that the probability is reasonable, because I have flipped through a deck a few times without repeating a value.  However, I believe that the probability is rather low.

Any advice on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310971/no-two-identical-ranks-together-in-a-standard-deck-of-cards

Comment: I would say that unless you're _really bad_ at shuffling, you will practically never get _any_ cards back-to-back. The only way to do that is to turn one of the cards over so that its face is where its back should be. :-)