# How many arrangements of the following?

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements (permutations) of a set of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ distinct cards, each having one of $n$ colors $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ where there are $i$ cards of color $c_i$ that are numbered  $1,2,\ldots,i$, satisfy the following constraint: any two cards of the same color and with consecutive numbers cannot be adjacent in the arrangement. This seems to be similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76213/), but in our case all the cards are distinct, whereas in that problem the cards of the same color are all identical.

Comment: How many cards are in an arrangement? Can you give an example of a forbidden arrangement?

Comment: Do you want permutations of the entire deck in which no two *adjacent* cards of consecutive numbers of the same color?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I mean. For example, case $n=3$, red 1, blue 1, 2 and green 1, 2, 3. Blue1 should not be adjacent to Blue2. Neither Green1 and Green2, nor Green2 and Green3.

Comment: Please, fix the question, so that it actually expresses what you mean. Then, please tell us where this question comes from and what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: I've edited the question to what seemed to be intended. Looks like a tough problem to me, considerably harder than the other problem linked to. Did you try do compute the numbers for small $n$, and used the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/)? Also, did you look at the [simpler problem](http://oeis.org/A002464) of permuting $n$ cards with consecutive numbers forbidden to be neigbours?

Comment: @Marc: I count $1,2,216,954432$ for the first four terms ([here's the code](https://gist.github.com/2349368)). That sequence isn't in OEIS.

Comment: $a(n)=\int_{z=0}^\infty \Biggl(e^{-z}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1-k} \binom{k+1}{j}\binom{i-1-j}{k}\Bigr)(-1)^{i-1-k}z^{k+1}\biggr)\Biggr)dz.$   
$a(1)=1, \;a(2)=2,\;a(3)=216,\;a(4)=954432,\;a(5)=313067602560,\;a(6)=11394325627300281600,\;a(7)=64336748997032761512891479040,\;a(8)=75093144953318072478960408305125194792960.$