# How many paths touch each node a given number of times?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many paths of length $N$ through a complete graph pass a given number of times $k_n$ through each node $n$ ($\sum_n k_n = N$)?

Answer (score 1):

We have a graph with vertices $1,2,3\dots j$ ,we want to know the number of paths of length $N$ such that for $1\leq i \leq j$ we have that vertex $i$ appears $k_i$ times. We are told $N$ is in fact equal to the sum of the $k_i$'s.

Every such path can be seen as a word of length $N$ which has $k_i$ appearances of symbol $i$, for $1\leq i \leq j$.

This problem has been solved before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129451/find-the-number-of-arrangements-of-k-mbox-1s-k-mbox-2s-cdots/129802#129802), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76213/how-many-arrangements-of-a-2b-3c-4d-5e-have-no-identical-consecutive-lett), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393038/how-many-words-can-be-made-with-7-as-6-bs-5-cs-and-4-ds-with-no-co/1393095#1393095).